# How to exclude java code processing from printing into Log file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a unix shell script which uses java program to process some file.

Script name is : Medica_auto.sh

to make a log file of console of this script i m using:

**Sh Medica_auto.sh >> Filelog.log**

But the process is : it will also print whole java code processing in log file as well which unnessary increase the size of log file.

I m using below code:

**$JAVACODE $INPUT$FILE $DIV_NAME $Mst_Grp $File_Mth $File_Yr**

IS their any way which i will not print the output of java code in console (in log file)??

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What does `Medica_auto.sh` contain?

Comment: Its is a script which process file from input dir and make output file in output dir.

Comment: 1. Your question isn't clear.  2.  You need to post your script in order to enable people to help you.

Comment: Is their any command to exclude line from print them from console..like we use 'ECHO' to print line in console...

Comment: This is working for me :like we use echo " FILE CANNOT PROCESSED !!"                                                       to print FILE CANNOT PROCESSED !! .... But if i use echo " FILE CANNOT PROCESSED !!"   >> NULL  ... Will not print anything

Answer (score 0):

> I m using below code:
>
> `$JAVACODE $INPUT$FILE $DIV_NAME $Mst_Grp $File_Mth $File_Yr`
>
> IS their any way which i will not print the output of java code in
>   console (in log file)??

Assuming that you don't want the output of the above line in your log file, you can replace it with:

```
$JAVACODE $INPUT$FILE $DIV_NAME $Mst_Grp $File_Mth $File_Yr >/dev/null 2>&1
```